# How can I ignore annoying users?

Tags: support, users

There are some guys who seem to be flooding or spamming me. Is there a way to ignore or block a user, like what can be done in Facebook, for example?

Answer (score 11):

No, you cannot ban a user. If you feel a user is trolling, flag one of their posts for moderator attention so they can look at it, and warn (or suspend) the user when necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I mean flooding, not trolling. Edited my question

Comment: @Antonio still the same answer.

Answer (score 4):

Only moderators can ***suspend*** users.

No users can be banned until moderators decide to ***permently destroy the account into shreds*** if that person seems to be too annoying in our digital society. Flag the user's post and in the `Other` section, write your reason for wanting that user suspended if necessary. Also give a friendly warning. If the user ignores it, it might go against that user in the future... Other than that, just go on with life as we know it today.

Comment: banning != destroying the account. Bans can be temporarily

Comment: Actually that's not what I mean. I just do not want the noob to see my questions and me to see his

Comment: That is not possible really. Anyone can visit your profile so the only way is to change your username. And that might still not work